# MSI install powershell program but no modules available

Tags: powershell

I installed AutomatedLab.msi from here - https://github.com/AutomatedLab/AutomatedLab/releases
it installed without any errors but there doesn't appear to be any powershell modules available... or it doesn't seem to know where the modules are?  Is there anything else that I can do...

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads> Get-LabAvailableOperatingSystem -Path C:\LabSources

Get-LabAvailableOperatingSystem : The term 'Get-LabAvailableOperatingSystem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-LabAvailableOperatingSystem -Path C:\LabSources
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-LabAvailableOperatingSystem:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Is there some special way I'm supposed to install msi executables?  Ive tried  'start-process' I've tried "Install-Module MSI" I can't seem to get anything to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: According to [the installation instructions](https://github.com/AutomatedLab/AutomatedLab/wiki/1.-Installation) the module should be in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`. This should be there by default, but can you confirm that directory is part of `$env:PSModulePath`, and ensure that the module is present in that directory?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Hi! Yep, the files are there and the directory is part of the module path.  I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Try listing the available command of the module and make sure that the command is really available `get-command -module AutomatedLab`

Comment: You normally don't use msiexec to install PowerShell modules. Is this an off line environment? Otherwise just use `install-module AutomatedLab`

Comment: When I try to install the module `AutomatedLab v5.39.0` on a clean computer, I get the following errors `The following commands are already available on this system: 'Get-LabAzureLoadBalancerPort,New-LabAzureResourceGroupDeployment'`. I suspect the module is faulty. Try registering an issue on their GitHub site. Or try installing an older version.